# If $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, is $f(x)$ continuous on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I am wondering if this is true. I have seen some books which say that $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ instead of $(a,b)$, and thus avoid this problem.

Comment: And even if $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$, $f$ needn't be continuous there, e. g. $$ x \mapsto \begin{cases} \sin x^{-1} & x > 0\\ 0 & x = 0 \end{cases} $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not true. Take
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x\in(a,b)$}\\
1 & \text{if $x\in \{a,b\}$}
\end{cases}
$$